# Fluent NhiberNate .net core 3.1 with sql server

Tags: .net-core, fluent-nhibernate

Recently I started working on NhiberNate with .net core and try something simple
I have a table like this:

```
public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
public virtual string Name { get; set; }
public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
public virtual int ClusterId { get; set; }**
```

Mapping like this:

```
Id(x => x.Id).Column("Id").GeneratedBy.GuidNative();
Map(x => x.Name);
Map(x => x.LastName);
Id(x => x.ClusterId);
```

Now Guid is the primary key, clusterid is just identity, I created table first and manually insert data in it, a guid created at the server-side like this

```
37815D12-C7BF-4575-9786-306D56DCB86D
```

But when I get the data from DB via postman or etc. Guid return like

```
00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
```

I return data on the code like this `return _session.Query<CustomEntity>().ToList();`

I tried change mapping with `.GeneratedBy.GuidComb();` and `.GeneratedBy.Guid();` but doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `Id(x => x.ClusterId);` to `Map(x => x.ClusterId);`. Having two Id mappings can cause all kinds of problems.

Comment: Thanks a lot ,this solved my problem.I guess I just misunderstood the id consept for nhibernate mapping through the samples ,cuz ClusterId is not primary key but identity and has autoincrement on my table.